# Testing memcpy function

Tags: c, testing, memcpy

```
void *memcpy(void * dst, static void *src, size_t n)
{
  Char*ret;

  if (dst == NULL || src == NULL)
    return NULL;

  ret = dst;

  While(n--)
  {
    *(char*) dst++ = *(char*) src++;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

I have some methods to test:

1. `if(dst==NULL || src==NULL)`
2. `n=0; n=1; n=65535;`
3. the input `(int,char ,float,double,class);`

Would there be more methods?

Comment: Please be more clear about your question.

Comment: Be careful when redfining such a function, `memcpy` is a reserved name and many compilers will replace calls to it with some inlined stuff before considering your code. If this is just an exercise, use another name to avoid such conflicts. If this is thought as a replacement of the c standard library, look into the documentation of the compiler to see how to switch builtins off.

Comment: Methods? You mean possible pitfalls? What about aliasing  (copy n>1 bytes from x to x+1 or vice versa)? Alignments (src/dst & 0x40 == or != 0)? page splits ((src + n) % 0x1000 != src % 0x1000)? Please post benchmark results if you want to understand them

Comment: my problem is how to to test the Memcpy() function(eg.white-box and back-box testing methods ).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you are testing `memcpy()`, you should *not* be privy to its code - or at least, do not assume that `memcpy()` will always be implemented as shown.  Your tests need to challenge `memcpy()` assuming it may have started as shown, but may morph over time.

---

An important method missing in the test is partially overlapping `dst` and `src`.

```
extern void *memcpy(void * dst, const void *src, size_t n);
char buf[50] = {0} ;
strcpy(&buf[5], "1234567890";
memcpy(buf, &buf[5]);
// what is the result?
char buf2[50] = {0} ;
strcpy(&buf2[0], "1234567890";
memcpy(&buf2[5], buf2);
// what is the result?
```

---

Test cases on odd pointer values.  Some platforms have restrictions on pointer alignment.  A good `memcpy()` should take that into account and not seg. fault.  So I'd test some unaligned pointers too.

There exist, IMHO, *esoteric* platforms with various paddings.  Just noting that here.

---

If `NULL != 0`, `memcpy(dst, 0, 1)` *should* work and not seg fault.

---

One last oddball test: (not certain *how* to implement.) Insure the `src` and `dst` did not get *accessed* outside their allotted range.  `memcpy(dst, src, 1)` did not do something like `uint32_t t = *((uint32_t*) src)`.  Because even though only LSByte of `t` might be written to `dst`, the *access* of `src` outside its range is a no-no.

---

You could have some performance testing (speed), but I'm assuming this is simple a functional test suite.

---

Notes: Some *unconventional* OS's have `size_t` as signed.  (I think they are non-compliant)

BTW: `static` is very curious in `memcpy(void * dst, static void *src ...`, it results in a compiler error.  Assume you wanted `memcpy(void * dst, const void *src ...`

Answer (score 0):

> An important method missing in the test is partially overlapping dst
>   and src.

Traditionally*, behavior in memcpy is undefined if dst and src overlap. It also means that it's pointless to test this case. Use memmove for buffers which might overlap.

* Meaning: users expect it, the standards specify it so, and this is the case historically too.

Comment: This is more of an addition to an answer rather than an answer by itself and probably should just be a comment.  Moreover, this is on a question that is over 4 years old.  These 2 together make me think that you this post is not really adding much to the conversation here.